# Python dynamic bit manipulation example

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am currently writing a python program requires bit manipulation.

The input is a sequence of integer array, say

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

The output is to check if each of the integer equal or greater than 3. If yes, then 1, else, then 0. The output is an binary **integer**:

```
00111111
```

How can I do this?

If a new number came in, say 9. I need to remove the first number in the sequence, say 1 in the sequence. So my new sequence will be:

```
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Then the result should be `01111111`. But I want to use **left shift** operation to this from my old integer `00111111`. How Can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: What do you currently use to store the bits?

Comment: @bereal I have no idea yet. Is it possible to use a integer?

Comment: Want to tell us why you need to do this? Is it your homework?

Comment: Integer will not keep track of the leading zeros, so `0011` and `11` are the same. The simplest way would be using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and `popleft` to remove the leftmost element.

Comment: @bereal Thanks. I think it doesn't matter 0011 or 11. Because in the final step, I want to test if this integer is 11111111.

Comment: The problem is, that left shift of `0011` and `11` in your case are the same, `1`, while you need it to be `011` and `1` correspondingly. An option would be implementing your own type with `<<` operation on top of `int`, but so that it counts the leading zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function like the following:

```
# Assumes msb first, lsb last, bits is iterable of integers in [0,1]
def bits2int(bits):
    v = 0
    for b in bits:
        v <<= 1
        v += b
    return v
```

Then, given your input array `arr`, call it with:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
val = bits2int([i >= 3 for i in arr])

print(val)                   # 63
print("{:08b}".format(val))  # 00111111
```

Same thing for your other input array, you could call it with:

```
arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
val = bits2int([i >= 3 for i in arr])

print(val)                  # 127
print("{:08b}".format(val)  # 01111111
```

**Edit**: From the last part of your question, it looks like you want to "update" `val` given some new integer.

This can be done using the above approach (update `arr`, call `bits2int` again on the updated `arr`), or "manually", with:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
val = bits2int([i >= 3 for i in arr])
# Now, val = 63 = 0b00111111

# Handle additional integer
new_int = 9             # Give the additional integer a name, to make it clear
val <<= 1               # Shift up all bits
val |= (new_int >= 3)   # Set lowest bit according to some logic
                        #   (here, if new_int >= 3)
print(val)
print("{:08b}".format(val))
```

At the end, val is the same as the output from the second `bits2int` call above:

```
127
01111111
```

Note that the `<<=` operator is in-place/augmented left-shift operator and the `|=` operator is the in-place/augmented bitwise-or operator.

---

**Update**

Per the discussion in comments, you not only want to keep track of the value, but also the number of bits.  This is more complicated than the simple function above.  Here's a basic class you could use:

```
class BitArray(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_array(cls, bits=None):
        self = cls()
        if bits is None: bits = []
        self.val = 0
        for b in bits:
            self.val <<= 1
            self.val += b
        self.nbits = len(bits)
        return self

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, val, nbits=None):
        self = cls()
        if nbits is None: nbits = val.bit_length()
        self.val = val
        self.nbits = nbits
        return self

    # Define equality
    def __eq__(self,  other):
        if self.val   != other.val:   return False
        if self.nbits != other.nbits: return False
        return True

    # Better representation of BitArray object
    def __repr__(self):
        return "BitArray(nbits=%d, val=%d)" % (self.nbits, self.val)

    # Output a binary string of nbits width, or width if specified (width must be >= nbits)
    def binstr(self, width=None):
        if width is None: width = self.nbits
        assert width >= self.nbits
        return "{:b}".format(self.val).zfill(width)

    # Conversion to int e.g. int(BitArrayInstance)
    def __int__(self):
        return self.val

    # "in-line" left shift
    def __ilshift__(self, n):
        self.val <<= n
        self.nbits += 1
        return self

    # "in-line" bitwise or
    def __ior__(self, v):
        self.val |= v
        return self

    # Helper function to generate a bit mask
    def _mask(self):
        return (1 << self.nbits) - 1

    # Trim n bits off the left side (truncate n most significant bits)
    def ltrim(self, n):
        self.nbits = max(0, (self.nbits - n))
        self.val &= self._mask()

    # "Pops" off msb, shifts all bits up 1, sets lsb to v
    def rotate_in(self, v):
        v = int(v)
        assert v in [0,1]
        self.ltrim(1)
        self.__ilshift__(1)
        self.__ior__(v)
        return self
```

Now, after you perform the same `<<=` and `|=` operations, you can remove the left-most bit / msb with the `ltrim` method:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b1 = BitArray.from_array([i >= 3 for i in arr])
print(b1)
new_int = 9
b1 <<= 1
b1 |= (new_int >= 3)
b1.ltrim(1)
print(b1)
```

This outputs:

```
BitArray(nbits=8, val=63)
BitArray(nbits=8, val=127)
```

Note that the `nbits` values are the same in the two print functions.  `<<= 1` will increase `nbits` by 1, then `ltrim(1)` will decrease it by 1, back to 8.  It does by "throwing out" the left-most bit like you asked.

I also threw in a convenience function for these 3 operations, `rotate_in(bit_val)`.  You could use this by:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b2 = BitArray.from_array([i >= 3 for i in arr])
print(b2)
new_int = 9
b2.rotate_in(new_int >= 3)
print(b2)
```

This outputs (same as above):

```
BitArray(nbits=8, val=63)
BitArray(nbits=8, val=127)
```

We can verify these two `BitArray`s are equivalent with

```
# Ensure b1 equals b2
print(b1 == b2)  # True
```

Lastly, just to verify this will work just as well for input arrays of length 600, we create a 600-element list of 1s, turn it into a `BitArray`, then compare the resulting value (with `int(BitArrayInstance)`) to what we expect it to be:

```
# Test 600 element array :)
arr = [1] * 600
b3 = BitArray.from_array(arr)
print(int(b3) == ((2**600) - 1))  # True
```

Comment: Hi, I got a problem. If the array is too long, say 600. does this program still works?

Comment: No, this approach will fail around arrays of length 31 (for a system using 64-bit integers).  Do you really need an approach that will handle arrays that long?? Note that an array of length 600 will represent an integer up to 4.149516e+180!  Are you working with integers that large?

Comment: but actually, when I was trying to work on 600 data points, it works.

Comment: @lserlohn, You are correct, I apologize.  `int`s will get automatically promoted to `long`s which will use arbitrary precision arithmetic and evade the traditional 8/16/32/64 bit restrictions that you would have in other languages due to overflow.  So I agree, the function will work for arrays of length 600, my mistake. :)

Comment: Thanks so much. Still have a question. If the new value come in, how do you remove the leftmost bit in this case? I think val <<= 1  will increase the total number of bits.

Comment: You're right that it will increase the number of bits.  But identifying what bit you should remove is a bit more difficult, let me throw something together and edit it into my answer -- it may take a few minutes.

Comment: @lserlohn I updated the answer with a skeleton class that will do what you want.  There are usage examples below the class that should help explain it.  Let me know if anything is unclear.